# Jquery icheck plugin click trigger on load function

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, icheck

I am facing some issue Jquery icheck onload function click trigger for example:- this is my function and what I am trying to do...

```
function resetfilter() {
  $('.filtercheckbox').each(function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (isChecked == true) {
      $(this).trigger('click') /// this case trigger not working with iCheck Jquery Plugins . can you suggest me how to execute trigger function onclick=" resetfilter()" this function
    }
  });
}
```

Here is my html...

```
<input class="icheck onclick="filterData();"  filtercheckbox filter-nn" type="checkbox" checked value="1">
<input class="icheck onclick="filterData();" filtercheckbox filter-nn" type="checkbox" checked value="2">
<input class="icheck onclick="filterData();"  filtercheckbox filter-nn" type="checkbox" checked value="3">
<input class="icheck onclick="filterData();" filtercheckbox filter-nn" type="checkbox" checked value="4">
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-round btn-sm" onclick="resetfilter(this);">Reset</button>
```

on load this function resetfilter() need to run click trigger for this function filterData() one by one .....?

Comment: Can you create an example on https://jsbin.com/ so that we can see the behaviour.

Comment: @unicorn2 unable to open properly ..? jsbin.com

Comment: Can you open this one: https://jsfiddle.net/ Paste all your html and JavaScript there.